# iOS Audio Toolbox buffer size

Tags: ios, audio, frameworks, buffer, sampling

In an iOS application, the minimum buffer duration of 4 milli seconds is required.
But the **Audio toolbox** framework provides, 23 milli seconds for 16kHz, mono channel configuration. i.e. it gives **742/744 bytes** at each input callback.

How to make the callback data size as, 128 bytes (4 milli seconds)?

Whether the internal mic (16kHz) or external mic (44.1 kHz) is used, the received callback size is 742/744 bytes (16kHz) only. Not clear about this behavior.

Whereas, in 'AudioUnit' framework, the callback data size gets corrupted, when an extenal mic (44.1 kHz) is connected.

Comment: I think what you need is to set     kAudioSessionProperty_PreferredHardwareIOBufferDuration: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Cookbook/Cookbook.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH6-SW36

Comment: I have already tried the above settings. It is giving the following buffer sizes for the given buffer durations.  second        buffer size (bytes)
0.002 -> 46
0.003 -> 92
0.004 -> 92
0.005 -> 184
0.01 -> 370
0.02 -> 742
0.03 -> 742
0.04 -> 1486
0.05 -> 1486
0.06 -> 1486
0.07 -> 2972
0.08 -> 2972
0.09 -> 2972
0.1 -> 2972
But, not giving the expected buffer size.